# Why aren't the contents of my text file printing in python?

Tags: python, printing

I am trying to open a file after I have changed the contents of it. After I changed the contents, the file will not open and will not produce an output.

[first part of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgR1j.png)

[second part of code where issues are occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rukjj.png)

Comment: Please include code as text with formatting (use \` to format it as code)

Comment: You're never writing anything to the file. It's opening just fine, but there's nothing in it to read and print

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** (as this is clearly homework): instead of

```py
   ...
   print(x)
```

how might you [`write`](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-write-text-file/) to the file `fnumbers`?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the write method in Question 4, hence that is why there is no data to be read in Question 5

```
fnumbers = open("cube_numbers.txt", "w")
for num in range(1,20):
    if num % 2 != 0:
        x = num ** 3
        fnumbers.write(str(x) + "\n" )
fnumbers.close()
```

To answer Question 5, first open the file with read method and simply use for loop

```
fnumbers = open("cube_numbers.txt", "r")
sum = 0;

for num in fnumbers:
    number = int(num)
    if(number % 3 == 0):
        print(number)
        sum = sum + number
print("sum = ", sum)
fnumbers.close()
```